# TextBoxes randomly disappearing

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook-addin

I have developped an Outlook addin in order to transfer some mails to an external ERP and all was working fine until some months ago. Since then, on one of the dozens computers on which it works perfectly fine, three `TextBox`es started to randomly disappear.

I've put some log, since it's impossible to reproduce within my debug environment, and today I've found something that could be the problem, but I have no idea on how to fix it:

When they fail, the `CanFocus` property value of those three components are `false`, while `Enabled` and `Visible` are both `true` and the `Handle` property is properly set. I've read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.canfocus?view=netcore-3.1) that those properties were mandatory to allow focusing on a component. Of course when all goes fine, the `CanFocus` value is `true`.

The fix I had already tried was simply executing the following code in the `Form` on `Shown` event :

```
txtField1.Show();
txtField2.Show();
txtField3.Show();

txtField1.Visible = true;
txtField2.Visible = true;
txtField3.Visible = true;

this.Refresh();
```

Where `textFields` are extended `TextBox`es and `this` refers to the parent `Form` of those fields. This code is called when form is shown or when a dedicated button is clicked.

Strangest thing, we had the problem on Windows 7 with a 2016 Outlook, migrated it to Windows 10 hoping it would resolve it and finally even installed a brand new desktop with a fresh Windows 10 and Office 2016, and the bug is still there, only for this specific user...

Has someone an idea of what could go wrong ? or any methods to force the showing of thoses components ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : After Jimi's comment, I've added some logs to be sure that all the hierachy is Visible, Enabled and has an Handle. After analyzing the new logs, it appears that the whole hierarchy except for the three fields has all those three property in a valid state and the CanFocus property of each member is true.

Here is the logged hierarchy :

```
Logging object of Type Hermod2._0.clsCustomAutoCompleteTextbox : Hermod2._0.clsCustomAutoCompleteTextbox, Text: 
Property AutoSize : True
Property CanFocus : False
Property ClientSize : {Width=281, Height=16}
Property Enabled : True
Property Handle : 3279192
Property Height : 20
Property Name : txtPartner
Property Parent : System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox, Text: Dossier détecté
    |=> Logging object of Type System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox : System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox, Text: Dossier détecté
    |=> Property AutoSize : False
    |=> Property CanFocus : True
    |=> Property ClientSize : {Width=458, Height=113}
    |=> Property Enabled : True
    |=> Property Handle : 2952070
    |=> Property Height : 113
    |=> Property Name : groupBox2
    |=> Property Parent : System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
        |=> Logging object of Type System.Windows.Forms.Panel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
        |=> Property AutoSize : False
        |=> Property CanFocus : True
        |=> Property ClientSize : {Width=778, Height=399}
        |=> Property Enabled : True
        |=> Property Handle : 4130368
        |=> Property Height : 399
        |=> Property Name : panel1
        |=> Property Parent : Hermod2._0.CaseSearch, Text: Recherche de dossier
            |=> Logging object of Type Hermod2._0.CaseSearch : Hermod2._0.CaseSearch, Text: Recherche de dossier
            |=> Property AutoSize : False
            |=> Property ClientSize : {Width=783, Height=405}
            |=> Property Size : {Width=799, Height=444}
            |=> Property CanFocus : True
            |=> Property Enabled : True
            |=> Property Handle : 1379040
            |=> Property Height : 444
            |=> Property Name : CaseSearch
            |=> Property Parent : 
                |=> Can't log object, it's null...
            |=> Property Visible : True
            |=> Property Width : 799
            |=> Property PreferredSize : {Width=798, Height=442}
        |=> Property Size : {Width=778, Height=399}
        |=> Property Visible : True
        |=> Property Width : 778
        |=> Property PreferredSize : {Width=771, Height=358}
    |=> Property Size : {Width=458, Height=113}
    |=> Property Visible : True
    |=> Property Width : 458
    |=> Property PreferredSize : {Width=457, Height=115}
Property Size : {Width=285, Height=20}
Property Visible : True
Property Width : 285
Property PreferredSize : {Width=54, Height=20}
```

Here is a screenshot of the components when all goes right :
[image: Case all right]

And here is the screenshot of the exact same zone where it goes wrong :
[image: Disappeared fields]

Comment: [IsWindowVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowvisible) returns true only when all Controls in the child control hierarchy have the `WS_VISIBLE` style set. i.e., an ancestor of those controls is not visible. [IsWindowEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowenabled) checks just the child control. Both must return `true` for the CanFocus property to return `true`.

Comment: How can I use those functions in C# ? I've done a quick search, but I didn't found anything...

Comment: Those Win32 functions are called by the Framework when you inspect the [CanFocus](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,1400) property (.Net Source Code). The reason I mentioned these functions is because is clear what is expected from a Control to be focusable: all its parents in the *parenthood* chain must be visible for the `IsVindowVisible` function to return true. So, if your Controls `Visible` and `Enabled` properties both return `true`, then a parent in the chain is not visible (or enabled).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll add more logs to get info on the parents to gather information.

Comment: I've added some logs and screenshots to my question, I've checked all the hierarchy, and all properties seems fine